# ExpandedTile - BoxConstraints forces an infinite width

Tags: flutter

I'm creating an app and when I use the ExpandedTile it gives this error. can you guys help me?

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ════════

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

```
class PlayersTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final PlayersData data;

  PlayersTile(this.data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Image.network(
                data.image,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 150.0,
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      data.name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "DT\$ ${data.points.toString()}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ExpansionTile(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("teste")
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: does it tell you where in the widget tree this error happens? this is an essential piece of info. if you cant see that try putting widgets like row and expansible tile in a container with a given width see if that is the causing widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can wrap `ExpansionTile` with `Flexible` just like you do in `Image.network` and `Container`

```
Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: ExpansionTile(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PlayersData {
  String name;
  String image;
  int points;

  PlayersData({this.name, this.image, this.points});
}

class PlayersTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final PlayersData data;

  PlayersTile(this.data);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Image.network(
                data.image,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 150.0,
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      data.name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "DT\$ ${data.points.toString()}",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: ExpansionTile(
                children: <Widget>[Text("teste")],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            PlayersTile(PlayersData(
                name: "abc",
                image: "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
                points: 10)),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.